# I want to retrieve last year record from MySQL database but it's retrieving all data's from database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
string cmd = @"
SELECT Status,COUNT(Status),YEAR(Start_Date_Time) As LASTYEAR 
FROM sh_report 
WHERE 'YEAR(Start_Date_Time)' <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
GROUP BY YEAR(Start_Date_Time)";
```

Problem is getting all record but i want only last one year record from database can any one please tel me MYSQL Query to get last one year record.

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: Why are you adding a colon for the Year component in the where clause? Do you intend to compare the string with the value returned by the Date_Sub function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `LIMIT` to get what you want. [Here is more info on the LIMIT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx).

```
     SELECT Status,COUNT(Status),YEAR(Start_Date_Time) As LASTYEAR 
     FROM sh_report 
     WHERE YEAR(Start_Date_Time) <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
     GROUP BY YEAR(Start_Date_Time)
     ORDER BY YEAR(Start_Date_Time) Asc
     LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

select top 1 then use order by asc clause

Comment: `select top 1` is sql-server snytax. it doesn't work on mysql.

Answer (score 1):

The where clause of the query is comparing the YEAR component of Start_Date_Time as string with date string returned by the DATE_SUB function. Please refer to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate). Your where clause could be like this -

```
YEAR(Start_Date_Time) >= YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be corrected with following at where clause

```
WHERE 'YEAR(Start_Date_Time)' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

So it would be like,

```
string cmd = "SELECT Status,COUNT(Status),YEAR(Start_Date_Time) As LASTYEAR FROM sh_report WHERE 'YEAR(Start_Date_Time)' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) GROUP BY YEAR(Start_Date_Time)";
```